# Iterating through a CSV that has a number of all-caps names and changing them to proper capitalization

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, capitalization

I have a big table full of names, and some of them are all-caps. I'd like to go through the table and turn the all-caps names into regularly capitalized names. I have a couple of problems:

1. I'm pretty sure I'm not correctly turning the CSV into an array for Ruby to handle
2. When I use a bit of dummy data as the array I put through my .each loop, my .downcase!.capitalize! seems to work on the |word| while the .each loop is running over the array but then the array doesn't contain the fixed words at the end

Here is me attempting to turn the CSV file I have into a Ruby array:

```
require "csv"

puts "What is the name of the CSV you want to clean?"
print ">> "
csv_name = $stdin.gets.chomp

array = CSV.parse(File.open(csv_name, "r+"))
```

Here is the dummy data array, with the .each loop that is supposed to correct the capitalization of each all-caps entry in the array, and seems to do so, only it doesn't stick:

```
array = [["Thing", "Whatsit", "Object", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Let", "Get", "Met"],
[1, 2, 3, "NULL", 5, 6, "Stuff", "test", "CRAZY"],
["THING", "LADY", "TERROR OF THE NIGHT", "MIGHTY", "nothing", "SYCOPHANT", "NEXT", "WILD", "WIFE"]]

array[0..(array.count - 1)].flatten.each do |word|
  if word.to_s == word
    if word.upcase == word
      ary = word.split
      ary[0..(ary.count-1)].each do |w|
        w.downcase!.capitalize!
      end
      word = ary.join(" ")
      puts word
      word
    else
      word
    end
    word
  else
    word
  end
end

print array
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After capitalizing values will you be creating a new CSV file? If so, you can use other CSV methods to advantage, so it would be useful if you were to display an image of the CSV file for your example (with headers if applicable). One small thing, the elements of `array[1]` that are integers should be strings (e.g., `"2"`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I'll want to recompose the CSV file to resemble the one I started with, I hadn't even really started thinking about that part of the problem yet. Should I edit my post to mention that?

Comment: I'm not sure as it would change the question substantially, something that one generally should not do after an answer has been posted. The CSV file associated  with `array` evidently has three columns or fields. Are there headers for those fields? Note that `array[0]` and `array[1]` both have 9 elements whereas `array[3]` has 10.

Comment: The actual CSV I want to run through has 17 columns and 10000 rows, plus one header row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom converter when parsing the CSV to process the data on the way in. The CSV library comes with a set of standard converters that help parse integers, dates, etc., but you are free to define custom ones.

```rb
require 'csv'
CSV::Converters[:fixcaps] = ->(v) { v.capitalize rescue v }
CSV.parse(File.read(csv_name), converters: :fixcaps)
=> [["Header1", "Header2", "Header3"], ["Thing", "1", "Thing"], ["Whatsit", "2", "Lady"], ["Object", "3", "Terror of the night"],  ...]
```

(I slimmed down the test data somewhat, so it doesn't exactly match what you gave.)

The customer converter simply downcases and capitalises. In the case where a error is raised (primarily because a field is `nil`, the converter simply returns the original data as a fallback.

### EDIT

I missed part of the question where only all-caps words needed to be fixed. There's a few ways to accomplish that via regex, but here is one:

```rb
CSV::Converters[:fixcaps] = ->(field) do
  field.gsub(/(?<!\S)[[:upper:]]+(?!\S)/) { |w| w.capitalize }
rescue
  field
end
```

Also, in one of your comments you mention the real data has headers and that ultimately you want to re-write as a CSV. You can handle both easily enough:

```rb
require 'csv'
CSV::Converters[:fixcaps] = ->(v) { v.capitalize rescue v }
data = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_name), converters: :fixcaps, headers: true)
File.write('output.csv', data.to_csv)
```

In this case, specifying `headers: true` causes `CSV.parse` to return a `CSV::Table` object instead of your original nested array (after running things through our custom converter). `CSV::Table#to_csv` then writes out the data in CSV format, headers first.

You can always call `.to_a` on the `CSV::Table` to get the equivalent nested array if you need it, but if you have other processing to do, `Table` provides tools for manipulating the data (e.g., switching between row/column orientation, dealing with only certain columns, etc.) that can be easier to wrap your head around than dealing with just the nested arrays.

Comment: I took what you suggested and replaced your custom converter with the `.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')` that @LesNightingill suggested, and it works beautifully! How do I split the credit between you two?

Comment: @Flynn this should be the accepted answer b/c it's the perfect solution, but you can upvote mine too!

Comment: Yes! Poor reading comprehension on my part. I've edited the answer to provide an alternative converter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```rb
array = array.flatten.map{|c| c.is_a?(String) ? c.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ') : c}
```

Comment: This works great to correct the capitalization!In order to turn the array back into a CSV with the same rows and columns, I think I need to unflatten the array somehow, after the capitalization fix, back to its layered self.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a CSV File**

Suppose we wish to read a CSV file whose contents are given by the contents of `str`:

```
str =<<~END
Fld1,Fld2,Fld3,Fld4,Fld5
Thing A MA-Jig,Whatsit,Object,FoO AND 1 GOO,Bar
1,NULL,Stuff,test,CRAZY
LADY,TERROR OF THE NIGHT,nothing,LEFT,nEXT
END

File.write('in.csv', str)
  #=> 140
```

Let's confirm it was written properly.

```
puts File.read('in.csv')
Fld1,Fld2,Fld3,Fld4,Fld5
Thing A MA-Jig,Whatsit,Object,FoO AND 1 GOO,Bar
1,NULL,Stuff,test,CRAZY
LADY,TERROR OF THE NIGHT,nothing,LEFT,nEXT
```

**Read the CSV file**

The trick here is to define a *custom converter* to perform a conversion of all strings having the property that all of the letters contained in the string are uppercase. The question asks that these strings all be capitalized.

Custom converters are procs that convert the content of certain fields as the file is read. [Here](http://rubyforadmins.com/lambda-functions) are some examples of custom converters. The custom converter we want can be written as follows.

```
convert_all_caps = ->(value) do
  value.gsub(/\S+/) do |word|
    word == word.upcase ? word.capitalize : word
  end
end
  #=> #<Proc:0x0000583f969bdf88@(irb):467 (lambda)>
```

The regular expression `/\S/` matches one or more characters other than whitespaces.

Note that the lambda has an optional second argument that is the name of the header (e.g., `"Fld2"`) for the value that is passed. This allows one to employ a case statement to convert different fields in different ways, should that be desired.

Here are two examples of the use of this lambda.

```
convert_all_caps.call('Thing A MA-Jig')
  #=> "Thing a MA-Jig"
convert_all_caps.call('FoO AND 1 GOO')
  #=> "FoO And 1 Goo"
```

If we read our CSV file with this custom converter we obtain the following.

```
csv = CSV.read('in.csv', :headers => true, converters: [convert_all_caps])
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:4> 
csv.to_a
  #=> [["Fld1", "Fld2", "Fld3", "Fld4", "Fld5"],
  #    ["Thing A MA-Jig", "Whatsit", "Object", "FoO And 1 Goo", "Bar"],
  #    ["1", "Null", "Stuff", "test", "Crazy"],
  #    ["Lady", "Terror Of The Night", "nothing", "Left", "nEXT"]]
```

See [CSV::read](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read).

**Write a CSV file**

If we wish to write these converted values to another CSV file the most efficient way is to read the input file line-by-line and for each line write a line to the output file. We can do that as follows.

```
headers = CSV.open('in.csv') { |csv| csv.first }
  #=> ["Fld1", "Fld2", "Fld3", "Fld4", "Fld5"]
CSV.open('out.csv', "wb") do |csv_out|
  csv_out << headers
  CSV.foreach('in.csv', :headers => true,
    converters: [convert_all_caps]) { |csv_in| csv_out << csv_in }
end
  #=> 140
```

See [CSV::open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) and [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach).

Let's confirm the output file was written correctly.

```
puts File.read('out.csv')
Fld1,Fld2,Fld3,Fld4,Fld5
Thing A MA-Jig,Whatsit,Object,FoO And 1 Goo,Bar
1,Null,Stuff,test,Crazy
Lady,Terror Of The Night,nothing,Left,nEXT
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It's a bit more ambitious than was necessary for my use case but I will definitely be coming back to this post to learn from how you did this next time I need to do something similar!

Comment: I removed the discussion of the special treatment of "little words" so that it would focus exclusively on the question.